# Have an Arrow point the way I'm aiming

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

I'm wanting my arrow to point the way I'm targeting in my game.

At the moment, my prefab instantiates in the center of the screen point to the left. When I move my arrow, the point still keeps to the left. How can I get it so that the arrow at least points to the center of my screen, or ideally, has a way of moving, depending on the direction the player is aiming.

For example, if my player is aiming to the top left of the screen, the arrow point would face that way and fire off in that direction.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
public Object _projectilePrefab;
private bool _pressed = false;
public GameObject _flystickPosition;

private GameObject _currentProjectile;

private Vector3 _firePoint;

private float _startTime;

public float sensitivityX = 15F;
public float sensitivityY = 15F;

int x = 0;
int y = 0;


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    _currentProjectile = (GameObject)Instantiate(_projectilePrefab, _flystickPosition.transform.position, _flystickPosition.transform.rotation);

    _firePoint = Camera.mainCamera.transform.position - new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
    _startTime = (Time.time * 10.0f);
    //_serialData = GetComponent<ReadSerial>();
    //_udpData = GetComponent<HV_ReadUDPData>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    _firePoint = Camera.mainCamera.transform.position - new Vector3(1, 1, 0);

    float _moveBananaY = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxisRaw("LeftRight") * sensitivityX;


    float _moveBananaX = transform.localEulerAngles.x + Input.GetAxisRaw("UpDown") * sensitivityY;
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_moveBananaX, _moveBananaY, 0);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        y--;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        y++;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        x--;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        x++;
    }


    float xPercent = 0;
    float yPercent = 0;

    xPercent = x / 25.0f;
    yPercent = y / 25.0f;


    _flystickPosition.transform.parent.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(xPercent * 90, yPercent * 90, 0.0f);

    float smooth = Time.time - _startTime;

    _currentProjectile.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(lerpFrom, _flystickPosition.transform.position, smooth);



    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        _currentProjectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = _flystickPosition.transform.parent.forward.normalized * 20;


        _currentProjectile = null;
        _currentProjectile = (GameObject)Instantiate(_projectilePrefab, _firePoint, transform.rotation);
        lerpFrom = _currentProjectile.transform.position;
        _startTime = Time.time;

    }
}
```

All of this code is found within my FireProjectile class. It is attached to my camera.

Comment: There is a game development site within Stack Exchange: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understand you correctly, your game is 2D. Its not important though. I would offer two solutions for your issue:

1. You can get your pointing direction by using simple vector math. Vector3(to - from). So your arrow pointing direction is : Target.transform.position - Player.transform.position. Now when it is pointing the right direction you can move it like:
   Arrow.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);

Also if your arrow must point to target, but stay in different position than player, just raycast from Player to Target, get raycast point and theres your arrow "to" Vector3.

2. If arrow always mimic user rotation, you can simply apply rotation to arrow Arrow.transform.rotation = Player.transform.rotation. If rotations don't match (i.e. your object is rotated), just add empty gameobject to mimic rotations and put arrow as child of it. now you can rotate it as you will.